# Delete Polygons And Extend Lines in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, line, geoprocessing

I am trying to do the same of Delete Polygons And Extend Lines tool, but I don't have because of the licence that I had.
It works to extend the line after deleted the polygon in between any 2-3 lines.
Can someone suggest another way to do the same even ArcPy script or by any geoproccesing tool.

[image: description here]

Comment: ArcPy will require the same level of licensing to run the geoprocessing tools.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that uses basic level license tools which you could put together in a model is this:

1. Intersect lake polygon with river network to create the in/out points.
2. Extract the XY of the two points.
3. Use the tool as described in [this](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012092) technical document to construct a line.

This approach works only for the simple scenario you show, lakes with multiple inputs will not work. You also do not show islands and what I suggest will cut through those.